# Does arcgis Map api supports for cluster locations in UWP windows application?

Tags: c#, uwp, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I have gone through that arcgis map documentation i have an requirement cluster wise displaying my location on map. Does this possible in C# UWP  mobile application Please share me code related to this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with arcgis and it's better for you to contact Arcgis directly for help [here](https://community.esri.com/community/developers/native-app-developers/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net). Some research results shows that it is possible for [point layer]( https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/configure-clustering.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_8D5C42DBE8A24A8B80FC3067DBB19D12) You may need to write code to see whether you can add this by using the code

Answer (score 0):

The ArcGIS Runtime doesn't support clustering out of the box at this time. You could probably build something yourself using GraphicsOverlays, by grouping features near by each other based on the current MapView.UnitsPerPixel value (ie split the view into 100x100px blocks, calculate how many would fall into each group, then render a graphic in each block that has one or more. Once a zoom is complete (NavigationCompleted event), if the UnitsPerPixel value changed enough beyond some threshold recalculate your clusters.